# Keeping up to date with updates?

Tags: windows, automation

I really like keeping up to date with the latest updates for my software.

I have Windows set to automatically download and install updates. But what about my other programs?

**How do I keep my 3rd-party software updated?** Especially if it doesn't have a "check for updates" feature.

**Edit:**

Recently ran across [this article](http://www.mytechguide.org/2009/08/19/keep-your-windows-up-to-date-with-these-utilities/) which lists:

- UpdateStar
- Filehippo.com Update Checker
- Update Notifier
- Secunia PSI
- SUMo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some of your software might be listed on **FileHippo**. You could download their [Update Checker](http://filehippo.com/updatechecker/), which will check for updates for your programs that they have listed on their website.

Comment: I went to check this out. They brag about it being lightweight and I like that :). I tried it out and it runs instantly and seems pretty cool. Good recommendation!

Answer (score 6):

If you're 3rd party software has an RSS feed on their web site you can subscribe to their feed with a rss reader (i use google's).  That way you can catch any headliners which hopefully will include any updates.

Answer (score 0):

[Secunia PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) notifies about updates to some applications, though the application itself can be somewhat annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The best one is [Software Informer](http://software.informer.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Ninite](https://ninite.com/) can not only install a number of programs unattended but it can also perform updates too. I simply run the installer every couple of weeks and everything I have installed gets updated.

On my parents computer I have a VBScript which waits a month and prompts them to update their software. They can press "No" and it'll defer for 48 hours. After 14 days, they can only press "Okay". At that point, Ninite runs and performs the updates.

In the future, I plan to tidy up and release the script - which will also include add the ability for it to close any running programs which might prevent an update occurring (and restart them afterwards) and also make it delete any additional icons which are added to the desktop during the update.