# Maintain all programs up to date on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, updates

Is there any program in Windows that would notify me when some program that I have installed can be updated or upgraded because a new version has been released?

Comment: If there were such a thing, would you trust it?

Comment: cwrea, why not?

Comment: I trust the one I use on Arch Linux and if Microsoft would offer something similar I would definitely use it.

Comment: @nagnatron Have you not seen Microsoft Update? That will notify updates for their main applications, like Office and Media Player.

Comment: Of course but that is a pretty limited subset of applications that I'm using on Windows. Windows Live, for example, is not updated trough Microsoft Update.

Comment: Allow me to me elaborate: If a third party tool offered to look for "updates" for *all* of your installed software, and let's say it also offered to download (and maybe even install) those updates, would you trust it? Let's assume the tool is *not* from Microsoft. How would you know the source for any given update is genuine, and not a trojan? Wouldn't you also be concerned that a list of all of your installed applications may be sent to a third party?  Just some food for thought -- you might not want to use such an app, even if something like that existed.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/2403/keeping-up-to-date-with-updates

Comment: cwrea: any third party application, not only the software updater, could do that. And I'd be happy if this updater only pointed me to the download page, that's enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Filehippo](http://filehippo.com/) has a version checker.

They seem to maintain their own database for program versions, how reliable that might now be.

Comment: I personally just got the exe version from them, with no installer or anything resident in memory. I just launch it occasionally. So it's not completely automatic, but it satisfies my need for constant upgrades.

Comment: Of course, this only supports applications via FileHippo...

Comment: Well, one can check the list of applications on their webpage, or alternatively, run the version checker software, and see if it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

In short, not for *every* piece of software.

To achieve this, you'd need to have *every* vendor support some kind of open interface for notifying of updates. Some of the the larger vendors have solutions that capture all updates for their software (like Windows Update, and Adobe Updater) but at present, there isn't a solution for all vendors in a single place

Comment: Well, for Mac OS X there are several directories of software and programs that check your local versions against them. It's not fool-proof but it works quite well.

Comment: They're still not going to cover *every* application you have

Comment: They surely are not going to cover every application, but with the set I have installed, they'll probably will. Thanks for the answer, I'm checking it now.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider Secunia PSI (http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/). It is free for personal use. It is aimed at security, so it might not be exactly what you were looking for. I have used it and found it to be very comprehensive. In fact it was kind of a pain at first. Once I got everything up to date it was fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [FileHippo.com Update Checker](http://www.filehippo.com/updatechecker/)

The Update Checker will scan your computer for installed software, check the versions and then send this information to FileHippo.com to see if there are any newer releases. These are then neatly displayed in your browser for you to download.

And the good thing about FileHippo.com is that they make the beta versions available for download that you normally wouldn't find on other download sites.

Answer (score 1):

[Software Updates Monitor](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) does what you want to achieve. It scans the installed programs (from your Programs and Start menu) and checks if their database has an updated version recognized. You can also add custom locations for software if you have something installed which is not recognized automatically or correctly.

The default version of SuMo comes with an optional component "RK" which is something like a IE-toolbar. You can disable it during the install or download the Lite-version of SuMo upfront (use the icon with the stroked graph) if you do not want to install this "Relevant Knowledge".

Comment: I have experience with this and can confirm that it does work well to a certain extent, but somtimes confuses operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking [ketarin](http://ketarin.canneverbe.com/). It's keeping all your installation packages up-to-date. Artenatively you can try win-get. It's analogue to apt-get for linux, but i think this project is dead already

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows isn't a linux distro, there isn't such tool ;)

Anyway, even if you don't fully trust it, there are some solutions which does quite a good job in keeping you notified when updates to your software are available.

I recommend [update notifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html). Keep in mind it doesn't support every little piece of software out there, but it does pretty good job on the most popular once (and some of the less popular).

Comment: Linux distros still don't fit the bill, as they can't copy with *every* application...

Answer (score 0):

I too (@moshe) have used [Cleansofts.org](http://cleansofts.org/) update notifier without problems for the more important programmes. You can ignore software and choose which to download the updates for. They link to their own "checked for viruses etc." downloads. Run auto or manual.

Answer (score 0):

There's [VersionTracker](http://www.versiontracker.com/windows/), and a slew of other programs.