# How to keep all your 3rd party Softwares always updated

Tags: windows, updates

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Keeping up to date with updates?](https://superuser.com/questions/2403/keeping-up-to-date-with-updates)
>   [Package managers for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows)

Is there any Windows software that checks for 3rd party installed software updates and automatically installs them . So that all my software are up-to-date.

Comment: Related / dupes: http://superuser.com/questions/2403/keeping-up-to-date-with-updates / http://superuser.com/questions/86462/package-managers-for-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Secunia Personal Software Inspector (PSI)](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) is a free program for home use that checks to see if your 3rd party Windows apps and drivers are up-to-date.  Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Secunia's PSI](http://secunia.com/vulnerability_scanning/personal/) and [FileHippo's Update Checker](http://filehippo.com/updatechecker/) come to mind.

Comment: Never tried PSI but an upvote for FileHippo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't an application that would do this. I'm not sure I'd trust it anyway - the possibility of it being hi-jacked are too great.

The best you can hope for is to choose applications that self update themselves. Most web browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc.) do this, as do Adobe reader, Apple products and the Java runtime.